# Why "/shared" directory is not listed while we do `hadoop fs -ls` , though it is visible when we do `hadoop fs -ls /shared/table_name`

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I perform a `-ls` command the `/shared` directory is not listed

```
[cts573151@aster2 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls

drwx------   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-12-21 05:30 .Trash
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2017-02-01 12:28   .sparkStaging
drwx------   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2017-02-02 11:37 .staging
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-12-19 11:40 _sqoop
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-12-12 15:02 externaltables
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-12-20 17:00 inputfiles
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-11-11 10:18 jars
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-12-07 17:05 outputfiles
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-11-29 11:53    pigoutputfiles
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2017-02-01 14:52 sqlimport
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2017-02-02 11:36 sqlimport1
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-11-11 14:46 ‘
```

But when I try to list it using specific `-ls /shared`, I get the files stored in it:

```
cts573151@aster2 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /shared
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573182 supergroup          0 2017-02-02 09:56 /shared/emp_sal
drwxr-xr-x   - cts550508 supergroup          0 2016-06-06 18:55 /shared/sampletable
```

Why is the directory not being listed but is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you do `hadoop fs -ls` without specifying any path, the default path which is considered is `/user/<username>/` and the directories & files inside `/user/<username>/` are listed.

As the folder you have mentioned i.e. "/shared" is at the root level, it will only be listed when you explicitly provide the path from root directory on hdfs e.g. `hadoop fs -ls /`

You can check this by executing commands `hadoop fs -ls` and `hadoop fs -ls /user/cts573151`. Both of them should give you the same results.

ref: http://www.slideshare.net/prdp6787/interacting-with-hdfs #20

Comment: Got It Thanks @daemon12